# Database for newspaper website

Tags: database

In a newspaper website one article may have so many word. So is it a good way to store the article in the database. If the answer is "No" then tell me the proper way. How the newspaper sites manage their huge content and show them on website.

Comment: Most of news sites store the datas on database.

Answer (score 0):

> So is it a good way to store the article in the database.

Yes. Text should be stored in database(s). 
In most cases all multimedias: images, movies, musics are stored direct on server.

But if we are talking about the biggest websites, some static content - like article which doesn't change during it's publishing life - may be stored as compiled static content.

For example yourservice.com/mega-news-aliens-are-around-us-this-is-the-proof may be stored as html direct on server's cache. 
And served direct by web server software (Apache/IIS/ etc. ) without php/.net/java...